# Scroll event in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Using Phonegap I'm trying to update an element when the user scrolls. Using `window.onscroll`, the event is only triggered once the scrolling has finished. I need to react on the scrolling *while* the user scrolls. I found out you can use

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(){})
```

which seems to work well while the user has his (her) finger on the screen, but if he flips the content and and releases his finger, the event will only be triggered after the scrolling has stopped.

Is there any way to track the scrolling while the user scrolls in Phonegap?